# Scrollable divs without absolute positions

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to make something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wwr2ny27/, but without the absolute positions for left and right panel? I want to make them scrollable, but without the absolute positions.

HTML:

```
<div id="header">Header</div>

<div id="left">
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    ...
</div>

<div id="right">
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    background-color: silver;
    height: 30px;
}
#left, #right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
#left {
    background-color: yellow;
    left: 0px;
}
#right {
    background-color: orange;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could check out this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/14wnj9x2/

So, I have removed the position absolute, and have totally based the code on height, which ensures that overflow occurs.

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100%;
}

#left, #right {
    float:left;
    height: 95%;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you..

```css
/* Styles go here */

body {
  margin: 0px;
}
#header {
  background-color: silver;
  height: 30px;
}
#left,
#right {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#left {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50%;
  height: 250px;
  float: left;
}
#right {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50%;
  height: 250px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="left">
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**OR**

you can simply add this..

```
#left,#right {
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div{ overflow-y: auto; }
```

it will add scrollbar only if it will be needed